# Warning: python is symlinked to python3

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, symlink

I am highly confident that some installation errors of some requirements in a repo I am working on relate to me using `pip` vs `pip3` and some symlink errors of my python installation.

I remember doing something silly to do with symlinks where I was trying to make the default python be python3 not python2 on my computer, but can't find the actual command I used for this (was on an SO answer).

I run `brew doctor` and get:

```
Warning: python is symlinked to python3
This will confuse build scripts and in general lead to subtle breakage.

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin/python3-config
  /Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin/python3.6-config
  /Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin/python3.6m-config
```

I installed python and python3 via homebrew via `brew install python` and `brew install python3`.

Running `python -V` as well as `python3 -V` gives me:

`Python 3.6.0 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.`

And `which python` gives me:

`/Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin/python`

And `brew info python` gives me:

```
python: stable 2.7.13 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13 (3,526 files, 48MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-04-14 at 20:39:38

You can install Python packages with
  pip install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

And `brew info python3` gives me

```
python3: stable 3.6.1 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1 (3,600 files, 55.8MB) *

  pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

What is going on here? Have I made the fatal error of installing the native python 2.7? I am on Mac OSX 10.12.4 (Sierra).

I tried `brew unlink python` and `brew unlink python3` and then `link` for both, but still got the same errors with `brew doctor`.

Comment: `/Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin/python` ← check your $PATH for miniconda.

Comment: In `.bash_profile` I have `# added by Miniconda3 4.3.11 installer
export PATH="/Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: I have a feeling I did the "just a warning" thing in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3 previously, somewhere on my system.

Comment: its funny that `brew info python` is 2.7, but `python -V` is 3.6 and `python3 -V` is also 3.6..

Comment: Because that `python` is miniconda's Python, unrelated to Homebrew :|

Comment: It looks like you have multiple environments. You could run `conda env list`. Use `source activate <envname>` to select the desired environment. `source deactivate` to get out of the environment. It looks like `brew` has it's set of pythons as well. Move the `miniconda` further down the `PATH`.

Comment: I only have one - # conda environments:
`#
root                  *  /Users/dhruv/miniconda3`. And `miniconda` line is right at the bottom of `bash_profile`.

Comment: It is right at the bottom of `.bash_profile`, but it is still be in the beginning of `PATH`. `which python` already revealed it. Move the `miniconda python` at the end of `PATH`, such that the output of `which python` will not be `/Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin/python`.

Comment: I should have spelled it out. `export PATH=/Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin:$PATH` is bad. `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin` is good.

Comment: OK this fixed the python3 symlink warning!! `which python` is now `/usr/local/bin/python` by just changing the `export` to append not prepend: `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin`. Final Q - I am still getting the config script errors `Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.` - are those a linked issue? You could add this to a final answer.

Comment: `which python` should produce something like `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13`. What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` show? I bet this is pointing to yet another python from another packager.

Comment: Do I just delete those old config files? e.g. `/Users/dhruv/miniconda3/bin/python3-config` so they don't conflict? or what?

Comment: `miniconda` will never interfere with `brew` unless you horribly created symlinks everywhere that you ended up with mixed pythons all over the place.

Comment: I get `lrwxr-xr-x  1 dhruv  admin  34 14 Apr 20:46 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python`

Comment: @alvits I think I did...how do I start fresh..

Comment: Here's why `brew` is confused. You probably have environment variables pointing everywhere such as PYTHONPATH and anything related to python.

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` is blank

Comment: I have no visibility of what you have on your mac. You should consider posting your issue on [apple stack exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or consulting someone who can look at what you have.

Comment: OK @alvits you fixed the issue in the Q, so post as answer and I will approve.

Comment: Before I post an answer, would you try removing `/usr/local/bin/python`? This should force `brew` to read `/usr/local/Cellar/....`. And remove `miniconda` from `PATH`. This will prevent `miniconda python` from getting read if the other 2 `python`s are not in `PATH`.

Comment: I'd like to, how do I remove it - just delete the folder completely? And don't we want minconda python to be read?

Comment: Here is apple question in case you think more valuable there. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280780/python-config-conflict-in-brew-doctor-and-symlinks-wrong-for-which-python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141749/discussion-between-dhruv-ghulati-and-alvits).